# VCR Sharing requests between cassettes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, vcr, poltergeist

My VCR config is:

```
VCR.configure do |c|
  c.configure_rspec_metadata!
  c.cassette_library_dir = 'spec/cassettes'
  c.hook_into :webmock
  c.ignore_localhost = true
end
```

And a test example is:

```
it "creates a build", :vcr => {:cassette_name => "build/feature/create"} do
  visit new_build_path(build)

  fill_in("build_name", :with => "Test Build")
  click_button("Create Build")

  build = Build.first

  page.should have_content("Build was successfully created.")

  current_path.should == build_path(hub)
end
```

When running this test it calls out to several 3rd Party API's which requests get recorded via VCR. The problem I am having is that it appears that VCR is using requests from other cassettes while running which is causing intermittent failures for certain tests. I have checked the cassettes and sometimes (depending on order is how it appears) all requests will be recorded and played back perfectly. It is worth noting this is when the whole suite is run, they always work when run by themselves. I do not share cassettes between the specs that fail, the only thing that is shared is some common requests to the API's and I force the naming of the cassettes just to make sure it is using the correct ones. I hope this makes sense...

My main question is what can be causing this problem? When using `record => :new_episodes` the tests work perfectly as well but not when using the `record => :once` mode. This may be okay given the situation but I want to make sure I am not creating unnecessary requests and from my understanding `record => :once` should work given the requests for each spec should be isolated.

I know this may be hard to answer without more information so let me know if any will help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is that? Capybara?

Comment: Yes, I am using capybara and the poltergeist driver for JS based tests

Comment: You need to mention that and tag your question properly or you won't get a good response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, it's hard to answer from the little bit of information you've given.  I can give some suggestions for helping to troubleshoot, though.

- You mention that you're using a capybara JS driver.  Capybara's JS drivers are asynchronous, which means that you test thread may continue on before your app has processed a particular request -- so if the test script continues on and ejects or inserts a new VCR cassette, and then your app makes an HTTP request -- it could lead to race conditions.
- VCR has a [debug_logger](https://relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/2-4-0/docs/configuration/debug-logging!) option that will give you lots of insight into exactly what VCR is doing.  It may answer your question.

Good luck!

Comment: Myron, thank you for the suggestions. The weirder thing now is that I have isolated the problem down to a spec file that has no JS tests. Is it possible that spec B using cassette B could use requests from cassette A from spec A? My understanding is it should not be the case but from the debug_logger and behavior appears to be the case. Just to clarify some more as well, running spec a by itself records the proper requests every time, but running spec a + spec b will cause spec b to miss some requests that are recoded in spec a. If there is anymore info that can help let me know. Thank you!

Comment: "Is it possible that spec B using cassette B could use requests from cassette A from spec A?"  Anything is possible, I suppose (software is complex, after all), but I can't imagine how this could be happening, given how VCR works. Each cassette is essentially a sandbox that is isolated from other cassettes. There's one exception to this: you can nest cassettes, and if the request doesn't match the inner cassette, it'll look in the outer cassette for a response. So, if the cassette is somehow not being ejected from spec A, then this behavior could result, I guess.

Comment: Update: An even more peculiar thing I noticed watching the debug logger is that when Spec A + Spec B are run the request that I thought was being shared before is actually not made (or at least not caught by VCR if it is, which I do not think is the case) but when running Spec B by itself the request is made... So the request is not being grabbed from another cassette it is actually never made/recorded but on re-run after cassettes are recorded it is requested so VCR throws an unhandled request error. I am at a loss with this one haha...

Comment: That suggests that it's not a VCR issue but rather a global state leakage issue--e.g. one spec changes some global state such that it triggers an extra HTTP request in another spec, but when the other spec is run standalone that global state hasn't been changed by the first spec, leading to this problem.

Comment: Myron, I think you are correct turns out this does not look like a VCR issue at all. Looking further into it and watching http requests just via the console when running these requests separately and right after each other there is definitely a state being saved. Thank you for all your help VCR is awesome btw!